# Cannot figure out how to save iptables on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora

I have a fresh install of Fedora 21 (I'm more familiar with Debian).  I'm trying to save IP table entries I put in.  On fedoras website, it says to issue the command `/usr/libexec/iptables.init save`.  This generates an error "No such file or directory"

```
[root@testpc /]# uname -a
Linux testpc 3.18.3-201.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 19 15:59:31 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64  x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@testpc /]# /usr/libexec/iptables.init save
-bash: /usr/libexec/iptables.init: No such file or directory
[root@testpc /]# find -name *iptables*.*
./var/lib/yum/yumdb/i/d44ff37d5f18866f386adc0de9fad24bc3be17c4-iptables-1.4.21-13.fc21-x86_64
./etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/iptables.pp
./usr/share/mime/text/x-iptables.xml
./usr/share/man/man8/iptables-save.8.gz
./usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz
./usr/share/man/man8/iptables-extensions.8.gz
./usr/share/man/man8/iptables-restore.8.gz
./usr/share/man/man1/iptables-xml.1.gz
./usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/iptables.aug
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you reverted to `iptables`? The default firewall in newer Fedora distros is `firewalld`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
# service iptables save
```